# How to set initial state for redux reducer in typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-reducers

I am getting this TypeScript error Property 'hasError' does not exist on type '(state: ErrorType | undefined, action: ErrorActionType) => ErrorType'. which I think its complaining about setting the initialState for reducer.

```
import { ErrorType, ErrorActionType } from '../actions';
import { ActionTypes } from '../types';

export const errorReducer = (
  state: ErrorType = { hasError: false, errorMessage: '' },
  action: ErrorActionType
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.setError:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and here is my action

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { ActionTypes } from '../types';

export interface ErrorType {
  hasError: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
}
export interface ErrorActionType {
  type: ActionTypes.setError;
  payload: ErrorType;
}

export const setError = (hasError: boolean, errorMessage: string) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch<ErrorActionType>({
      type: ActionTypes.setError,
      payload: { hasError, errorMessage },
    });
  };
};
```

and also my reducer.index

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { errorReducer } from './error';
import { loadingReducer } from './loading';
import { newsReducer } from './news';
import { schoolsReducer } from './schools';

import { StoreStateType } from '../types';

export const reducers = combineReducers<StoreStateType>({
  isLoading: loadingReducer,
  hasError: errorReducer.hasError,
  errorMessage: errorReducer.errorMessage,
  news: newsReducer,
  schools: schoolsReducer,
});
```

here is app state type

```
export interface StoreStateType {
  isLoading: boolean;
  hasError: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
  news: NewsType[];
  schools: SchoolType[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:  ***hasError typeof false*** as the parameter.

This is the problem that I encountered when using typescript with reducer and useContext together.

```js
export const setError = (hasError typeof false, errorMessage: string) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    ...
  };
};
```